# Svn treats my text file as binary

Tags: svn

I tried add auto-props to solve the problem that it treats .xml as binary.
But still some of files even .html .js treated as bin.
Show '(bin)' when imported.

How to let subversion always treat the file type as text?

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, XML files with a Windows origin often have "wide" encodings UCS-2/UTF-16 and automatically get `svn:mime-type` `application/xml` when *add*-ed to Subversion. You can suppress this behavior when you are adding files from the command line by specifying the `--no-auto-props` option:

```
svn add --no-auto-props <your file(s)>
```

You can always correct already added files with

```
svn pd svn:mime-type <your file(s)>
```

(This removes the `svn:mime-type` property from your file(s).) You may also want to set the `svn:eol-style` property so your diffs do not get messed up:

```
svn ps svn:eol-style native <your file(s)>
```

Here, instead of `native` you can also choose between `CRLF` (typically for Windows) or `LF` (typically Unix/Linux).

Answer (score 1):

By default, Subversion attempts to determine whether a file you add to version control is binary or textual and automatically sets `svn:mime-type` property to `application/octet-stream` (for binary file) or `text/plain` (for textual files). Read [SVNBook | File Content Type](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type) for more information about MIME and Subversion.

However, Subversion may incorrectly determine whether a file is textual or binary and will set `text/plain` property on some binary files or vice-verse. You can instruct Subversion client to set proper mime-type **on newly added files** properties based on file extension pattern automatically. See [SVNBook | Automatic Property Setting](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto).

*It's important to note that automatic auto-props work for newly-added files only! All existing files in the repository won't be affected by auto-props, so you need to reconfigure those properties manually.*

Answer (score 0):

Check these file. Possible they has 'binary' encoding. Subversion does not recognize wide encodings like UTF-16 (UCS-2) as text (and so does not perfrom merge, diff ..).

Thy to convert such files to UTF-8